# What is this lever?

Tags: part-identification, buick, old-cars

Recently I parked next to a (beautiful) 1957 Buick "Special" and took a bunch of photos. But I also noticed a lever to the left of the steering wheel, between the dash and the driver's side door, that I can't figure out what is for.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8zBDHZS.jpg]
[image: https://imgur.com/a/X47c0]

I hope these pictures are sufficient. Or should I ask in a dedicated classic car forum?

Comment: Thanks for putting the images directly in my post, that was my intention. :)

Comment: Just a question about your question ... isn't that the *left* side of the steering wheel?

Comment: Oh, you're right ... light ... reft? Gah. I fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not positive, but it looks like a vent actuator. In most older vehicles there were manual vents down in the foot well area of the passenger cabin. You'd have to reach down to actuate it by pulling/pushing a knob. Since Buick's were a little more on the "high end" of the car food chain, they would have such controls at easier access to the driver (possibly passenger as well). The control for the vent would be in close proximity so the driver wouldn't have to reach as far to activate it.

Comment: The more you know... I would _never_ have figured that out by myself.